# Why does TimeSpan use duplicated TimeToTicks?

Tags: c#, .net

TimeSpan has following constructors.

```
public TimeSpan(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    this._ticks = TimeSpan.TimeToTicks(hours, minutes, seconds);
}
public TimeSpan(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    this = new TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, seconds, 0);
}
public TimeSpan(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)
{
    long num = ((long)days * 3600L * 24L + (long)hours * 3600L + (long)minutes * 60L + (long)seconds) * 1000L + (long)milliseconds;
    if (num > 922337203685477L || num < -922337203685477L)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(null, Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_TimeSpanTooLong"));
    }
    this._ticks = num * 10000L;
}
internal static long TimeToTicks(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    long num = (long)hour * 3600L + (long)minute * 60L + (long)second;
    if (num > 922337203685L || num < -922337203685L)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(null, Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_TimeSpanTooLong"));
    }
    return num * 10000000L;
}
```

I think TimeToTicks is just a simplification version of the last constructor.

Why does the first one not use `this = new TimeSpan(0, hours, minutes, seconds, 0);`?

Comment: What would be `days` in first? It's not defined

Comment: Where is the duplication?  These constructors are all different.

Comment: @zerkms mistake. it should be this = new TimeSpan(0, hours, minutes, seconds, 0);

Comment: @ataravati I think it can use existing code 'TimeSpan(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)'

Comment: Where have you found this code? Could you provide a link?

Comment: @RenniePet ILSpy for TimeSpan

Comment: So what does TimeSpan.TimeToTicks() look like?

Comment: @RenniePet Code for TimeSpan.TimeToTicks() is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems be implement-specific. In Mono, it has following implement.

```
    public TimeSpan (long ticks)
    {
        _ticks = ticks;
    }


    public TimeSpan (int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        CalculateTicks (0, hours, minutes, seconds, 0, true, out _ticks);
    }


    public TimeSpan (int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        CalculateTicks (days, hours, minutes, seconds, 0, true, out _ticks);
    }


    public TimeSpan (int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)
    {
        CalculateTicks (days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, true, out _ticks);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess it was written by two different people or more and no one caught the inconsistency in the code.

Also, the first one does not use the overload `TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, seconds, 0)`, because there is no value for `days`.

However, you are correct that it could use the overload `TimeSpan(0, hours, minutes, seconds, 0)` though.

Answer (score 1):

As Karl Anderson says, it could be due to multiple programmers and lack of code review. But it might also be on purpose, to provide a minor performance gain for the first case. If I'm reading the code right, two multiplications and two additions are saved.

Edit: Just out of curiosity, have you tried looking at different versions of the .Net Framework? How about Mono's framework?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. in Mono, the several constructors always use a method CalculateTicks. So the question is just implement-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this could be written with less duplication, but the methods are not entirely duplicates. The constructor that accepts milliseconds adds 3 digits of precision to `_ticks`. For TimeSpans that have no milliseconds, `TimeToTicks` is more efficient and probably sufficient. Perhaps the real question is why there is no overload of `TimeToTicks` that accepts days (which the second constructor could have used).

Comment: '3 digits of precision' will not affect last result. in Mono, constructors just use CalculateTicks.

Comment: The values during calculation in `TimeToTicks` are 1000 times smaller than the ones in `new TimeSpan`, because it's done in units of seconds instead of milliseconds. It doesn't affect the result, but it probably affects performance.